# Authentication failed exception

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-mail

This is my code : pass field is not shown to you for privacy issue but i have put real password in my code

```
public static void send(String to, String subject, String msg) {

    final String user = "guru_190693@rediffmail.com";//change accordingly
    final String pass = "*******";


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");

    Session session;
    session = Session.getInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
        }
    });

    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);


        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();


        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");


        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String filename = "C:\\Users\\Harbir\\Pictures\\Photo0471.jpg";
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

}

It is catching an exception authentication failure 535 5.0.0 .I know there is a similar post like it but i didnt find anything helpful on that. Thats why i post it again. Help

Comment: You are using a `rediffmail` account credentials on `live.com` server. And hence the authentication failure error.

Comment: should i use a windows live account like xyz@windows.live.com  ??

Comment: You have to use an account that is acceptable with the smtp server `smtp.live.com`. I am not sure how an account of `live.com` looks like. I don't have an account on it.

Answer (score 1):

Change this part of your code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.live.com");
```

to

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.rediffmailpro.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

And for this to work, you need to upgrade your `guru_190693@rediffmail.com` to rediff mail pro account.

Comment: What is the alternative if user is not interested in a `pro` account.

Comment: yeah , exactly ... same question :/

Comment: Well just change the email provider you use. There are free services with google yahoo etc.

Comment: You can use port 465 insted of 587. 465 is universal port open for all servers. Just change write smtp.rediffmail.com as your host. Rest of code is perfect!